# NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError even when loading correct URL

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I am getting the `NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError` error for some users even if the correct URL is being used:
(pug syntax):

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places')
```

It seems to be resulting from the Authentication API call generated from the script.
Anyone else have this issue? How did you solve it?

Comment: Refer to my answer here for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092932/notloadingapifromgooglemapserror-occurring-randomly-with-google-maps-javascript/64314739#64314739

Comment: Refer to my answer here for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092932/notloadingapifromgooglemapserror-occurring-randomly-with-google-maps-javascript/64314739#64314739

Comment: @lukeupup This looks promising. I'll implement and monitor if the errors stop. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully others will find this useful - 
I received an answer from Google as follows:

> The API session token expires if someone leaves a map open for more
>   than about 24 hours, so it's normal to see a low level of these
>   errors. (This is the intended behavior)

There's no documentation about this anywhere - so hopefully this answer will help save people research time.

There might be a way to catch the error and re-authorize if it occurs. I'll update here if that's a possibility.

Comment: did you find a way to catch and re-authorize? We've never been able to reproduce this but see it all the time.

Comment: I had it in my email from my prev work. But don't remember the exact way to do it. You probably need to catch it globally and reload the page, though.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue for my site before and it was because of my service worker cache the google map API script. Once I unregistered my service worker the error stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this error on my site. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages, which says the following. Was was using python webassets to include the google maps javascript in a merged file, that appears to have caused this response. Interestingly, I had this merged file for a while, and the error response was something new.

```
NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError
       The script element that loads the Maps JavaScript API is not being included correctly
       on your page. In order for the API to work correctly, it must be loaded directly from 
       https://maps.googleapis.com.
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for the answer. I think that's a separate issue.
It's been a while since this q, IIRC, that error was one of the side-effects of the issue I describe in my answer.